# ADF Data Flow json Flatten Unroll by

Tags: json, azure-data-factory

I have a json result that should look like this:

```
{
  "TotalItemCount": 636,
  "PageIndex": 0,
  "PageSize": 20,
  "Result": [
    {
      "Id": "c02dd3ca-7440-4742-9802-af2b00655fe5",
      ...
      "Employment": [
        {
          "EmploymentNumber": "1234",
        ...
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      ...
    }
  ]
}
```

Swagger output:
[image]

However when it is setup with a REST Datatset source in ADF it seems like it adds a wrapping array like this:

```
[
{
  "TotalItemCount": 636,
  "PageIndex": 0,
  "PageSize": 20,
  "Result": [
    {
      "Id": "c02dd3ca-7440-4742-9802-af2b00655fe5",
      ...
      "Employment": [
        {
          "EmploymentNumber": "1234",
        ...
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      ...
    }
  ]
}
]
```

ADF Data flow source dataset output:
[image]

I want to flatten the items in the result in a data flow Flatten formatter but what do I put ion the Unroll by field when the anonymous array i added? Or do I need to perform something before the flatten to get all items in the Result array and the perform flatten on each of the items?
The data preview in the Source looks like this:
[image]

The result would be an array with Id and EmploymentNumber

Update: Setting the unroll by to body does not work
[image: unrollby]

Source projection:
[image]

Comment: Edit the question to add expected output as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- I have taken the data as shown below (The one you have given is not a valid).

```
{"body":[
{
  "TotalItemCount": 636,
  "PageIndex": 0,
  "PageSize": 20,
  "Result": [
    {
      "Id": "1",
      "Employment": [{
        "EmploymentNumber": "1234"
      }]
    },
    {
        "Id": "2",
      "Employment": [{
        "EmploymentNumber": "5678"
      }]
    }
  ]
}
]
}
```

- You can unroll by `body.Result.Employment` using unroll root as `body.Result`. Then select both the required id and employment number columns.

[image]

- This would give the result in the following way:

[image]

- Unroll on `body` with unroll root as `body`, you can select the required columns as well:

[image]

- Using this, the result would be:

[image]

Comment: Updated my post. The data does not contain an element called body which makes the unroll by settings not work, see image

Comment: So, the input is just an array? But where did the body in the source data preview come from

Comment: The source should be without the wrapping array but it seems that the ADF dataset adds this to the result?

Comment: I have tried them all (Single document, Document per line and Array of documents, with same result in Data preview

Comment: Provide the image of source projection. Clarify from where is this body coming in this image https://i.imgur.com/SPG0rms.png?

Comment: That image comes from Data preview. Also added the result of the projection which contains the body element. But it should not be ther, it's not inte the soure rest response but seems to be added within the ADF

Comment: Do you have access to storage accounts? If so, try writing the data directly to storage account as JSON file. If the source data is similar to the one given in the solution, you can use the above procedure.

Comment: Ok, now it's seems to be working. After I did the Import projection on the source then the Flatten picked up on the body selection. So that was what was needed, to Import Projection

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251923/discussion-between-hyzac-and-saideep-arikontham).